# how does my program find the file system path to a package?

Tags: ros, roslib, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When reading data files, it is often necessary for a program to find the file system path name for the containing ROS package. That may differ depending on where the package is installed on the system.

`rospack find` solves this problem from the command line and in shell scripts.

How do I find the correct path in a C++ or Python program?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9644/how-does-my-program-find-the-file-system-path-to-a-package?/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2011-04-05

Post score: 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I already knew the answer, but a colleague recently mentioned that it is somewhat buried in the ROS documentation. There are good answers on the [Packages](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Packages) page, however:

- [Python](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Packages#Python)
- [C++](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Packages#C.2B-.2B-)

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 15